# Compare 2 Excel files with the same number of columns, but different number of rows python

Tags: python, pandas, compare, comparison

There are 2 files. They need to be compared. It is known that lines can change places, the number of lines can increase (new positions can appear). It is necessary to highlight / display those values ​​that have changed. It is desirable to display old values ​​as well. I tried like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('2.xlsx')
df1 = df1[15:]

df1['Unnamed: 1'].loc[15]='Index'
for n in range(4, df1.shape[1],2):
   df1['Unnamed: %s'%n].loc[15]=df1['Unnamed: %s'%(n-1)].loc[15]
df1.columns = df1.loc[15:16].fillna('').apply(' '.join).str.strip()
df1 = df1[2:]

df1.reset_index(drop=True).head()
#df1 = df1.set_index('Index')

df2 = df2[15:]
df2['Unnamed: 1'].loc[15]='Index'
for n in range(4, df2.shape[1],2):
   df2['Unnamed: %s'%n].loc[15]=df2['Unnamed: %s'%(n-1)].loc[15]
df2.columns = df2.loc[15:16].fillna('').apply(' '.join).str.strip()
df2 = df2[2:]

df2.reset_index(drop=True).head()
#df2 = df2.set_index('Index') 
difference = df2[df1!=df2]

difference.fillna(' ')
```

If I set the "Index" column with the index, then the program breaks when replacing rows and does not work at all when I add new rows.
If I do not set the "Index" column, then when changing rows in places, it highlights all two rows.
The files are located at the links:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lprDyfSISL-Dtk-lZFKcOOCxVDU3ni5qBLkFEgS9fY0/edit#gid=1959535501

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z1OunDucKmKpPtWqUb1bEG0Rj4ZOC-qZtTNKBn3G7MY/edit#gid=1796031991

Comment: this is quite difficult due to the where the data actually starts, is that consistent across the excel files?

Comment: @Umar.H yes, of course, I took 2 files( available on link) and prepare for comparising

Comment: @Umar.H I saw you decision https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306685/compare-two-excel-files-that-have-a-different-number-of-rows-using-python-pandas but ,unfortunately, it is not working correctly in my files

Comment: I wonder if https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html would be useful at all... I haven't used difflib myself, so I apologize if this is off the mark